# Each time I minimise and reopen my Java window, the graphics change

Tags: java, swing

I got a bit of a problem which I am completely baffled about. Not even sure where to start to debug the problem.

I have a JFrame which promotes the user to enter a number, lets say the number was 4. I sent this number to my paint component to create a vertical line of 4 x 50. SO the line should be 200 in length. Which it does.

But if I minimise and reopen the window, that 4 seems to be multiplied again by 50 giving 200. Then that again is multiplied by 50 making the line 10,000.

I placed my paint component code in hope that it would help as the issue must be there, but if more code is needed I'll be happy to post.

```
class mainPanel extends JPanel
{
    int processes;
    public mainPanel(int x) //the value x is passed from another class, this was the number the user chooses...i.e 4
    {
    processes = x;
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 5));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension (1000, 1000);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);   
    int storedProcesses = processes;

        // Draw Title
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 28)); 
        g.drawString("We place the title here",380,50);
    processes = processes * 50;
    g.drawLine(100,100,100, processes+100); //Vertical (down) line

    //labels for vertical line
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    int y = 125;
    for (int i=1; i<=storedProcesses; i++) //this loop keeps repeating and getting larger for some unknown reason...then its repainting my JFrame
    {
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(i), 70,y);
        y=y+50;
        System.out.println("Loop" + storedProcesses); //used for debugging
    }

    g.drawLine(100,processes+100,1000,processes+100); //Horizontal (across) line
    }  
}
```

I've attached some screen shots to illustrate what's going on with 1 process as an example.

Before I minimise the window (this is fine):

[image: This is before I minimise the window]

This is after I minimise and re maximise the window

[image: After I minimise and remaximise, i get this result]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: BTW - `new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20)` would best be `new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 20)` for both compile time checking and cross-platform reliability.

Comment: It could simply be that un-minimizing a window calls `repaint()` on java components. A simple debug line at the beginning of the method can help verify that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks andrew, I shall keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control when Swing invokes the paintComponent() method. Therefore you should NEVER change a property of your class in the paintComponent() method. All variables that you manipulate in the paintComponent() method should be local variables.

```
processes = processes * 50;
```

Your current code is modifying the "processes" variable. Don't do this.

Comment: Thank you for that, never realised one couldn't control the paintComponent